# Database migrations for MS Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, migration, data-migration, database-migration

There are a lot of database migration tools available for Ruby, .NET, SQL Server, etc.

Is there anything good for Access/VBA? I've had to roll my own a few times, but I'd really like to offload that burden onto a well-written tool.

The ideal solution would be something like [FluentMigrator](https://github.com/schambers/fluentmigrator) or [RikMigrations](http://www.rikware.com/page/RikMigrations.aspx) with classes or modules that contain DAO code.

Comment: So access is the starting point of the migration. What's the end point? Another DB? Another version of Access?

Comment: Schema changes in an Access application. When rolling out a new version of a frontend, have SQL scripts or DAO object manipulations that get run on the backend.

Answer (score 0):

When there are only new columns to add personally I tend to do this in the user interface.  I have a temporary table in the backend database which is never locked by any users and when creating a new column I add it 1st to this table and double check all the properties are correct.  Then when the users are not using the backend database I copy and paste it, then allow users back in.

This means the backend database is unavailable for the shortest period of time and I am not rushed when creating the columns.